# .DS_Store file problem

Tags: macos

Can I remove the .DS_Store file from a predefined folder/folders for forever?
I got an example how to remove from this file from the network drives, but I would like to set specific folders. Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with built-in services, no.  Check out [BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/).

Comment: I also found the BlueHarvest, but do you think I can't solve with built-in services? There is no chance for this? :(

Comment: Not unless you're willing to write an equivalent application, no.